# Unable to open Queue from WCF windows service

Tags: wcf, msmq

I have a problem in getting WCF Windows Service reads from un-authenticated public Queue in another server in another domain.

Both servers are Windows Server 2008 R2.

When i set the windows server running user as Network Service , i receive **MQ_ERROR_ACCESS_DENIED (0xC00E0025)**. When i set the user of the windows service to Local System  i receive a different error **A security package specific error occurred (80070721)**

Is there any configuration i'm missing at any of the 2 servers? I enabled DTC at both sides

Comment: Please don't prefix your titles with things like "MSMQ- ". On [so], we use tags for that purpose.

Answer (score 1):

If you are going cross domain you need to grant receive permissions on the queue to "Anonymous Logon"

Comment: Anonymous logon is granted full control over the queue

Comment: Could you please answer http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9702379/queuing-in-oneway-wcf-messages-using-windows-service-and-sql-server ?